# Can I have a logo image inside a nav element?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, nav

In the interest of writing semantic and solid markup, can I position a logo image inside a nav element? Right before the ul element.

```
<nav>
    <img id="logo" />
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Or should I wrap it all in another element like so:

```
<section id="navigation">
    <img id="logo" />
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

I would prefer the first one to minimise the markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's no problem with placing an image within a `<nav>` tag. Per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/nav) and [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-nav-element), flow content is permitted content for this tag and among many other elements is the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 8):

I'd only insert an image in `nav` if …

- … this image is linked to a page/anchor (for example a link to the front page), or
- … this image contains the text "Navigation" or similar (so it should be inserted in a `h1`)

The [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-nav-element.html#the-nav-element):

> The `nav` element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.

So this section shouldn't contain things not about navigation.

Your second example is not what you want, because you would create a wrong outline (because of the outer `section`).

If it's the main navigation of the page and the image is the site logo, I'd use this markup:

```
<header>

 <h1><a href="index.html" title="Home page"><img src="logo.png" alt="ACME Inc."></a></h1>

 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li>a</li>
     <li>b</li>
   </ul>
 </nav>

</header>
```

If you'd like to link the logo to the home page *and* the home page is not linked in the `ul`, I'd insert it in the `nav`:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html" title="Home page"><img src="logo.png" alt="ACME Inc."></a></li>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

But this is a rare case, because you would still need a page heading and in most cases this would be the logo, and in most cases this should be linked to the home page of the site.

Comment: Sorry if this comment seems a bit random, but I have one question. Do you mean that in case the Logo replaces the link often called 'Home', it should be *inside* the `ul`, but when there is a link 'Home' and the Logo is also linked, then the logo should be *outside*  of the `ul` (but the Home-link of course inside)?

Comment: @Sven: If you have both, a linked logo and a link "Home", only the "Home" link should go in `nav`, yes. If you have a linked logo only, and this logo represents the site title (which is the case for most sites), it should *not* go in `nav`. My last HTML example is only for rare cases (and you’d need an additional site heading, then).